# Indent tableview content

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a rather simple question about TableView's in iOS, is there a way to indent the contents of the cells in a tableview, say for example I have an array of strings, and I want to have them displayed on the ui as alternating series of text, it would look like a conversation log. eg.

```
I am Hercules
                     I am Delilah
If you are Delilah
             Then I am your lover
```

This without resorting to custom cells, however, if the custom cells is the only, can you please show me how/where to start?

TIA

mirage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, do something such as this:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
  [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
} else {
  [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
}
```

Updated with correct alignment, thanks paul polo

Comment: although if it is really a conversation, you would probably want the if to check who the message is from.

Comment: @Rawkode, you're answer wasn't exact however, it uncover the stone for me to find what I'm looking for. So for those who might stumble here with the same issue at hand, you may try [code] cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight or [code]cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up when creating a cell in `tableView : (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

1. Check basing on `indexPath` whether you are creating odd or even cell.
2. Set text alingment for label within the cell. (you may alternate its origin point as well)

And you're done!